# How does this selectItems field get saved into the database

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I was reading this blog: http://andrejusb.blogspot.ca/2015/06/select-one-choice-with-select-items-tag.html

He creates a custom selectItems which has the list of values in a bean. The other fields are bound to a view which corresponds to a table in the database. When the user clicks save all these fields will be saved, but I do not understand how this new custom selectItems will be saved. It isn't binding to any table in the database. How would this work? How can we save this custom list of values to the database?

Answer (score 0):

He was just demonstrating how to create bean-based selectItems. When user selects, you need to capture the index of selection in your backing code:

```
<af:selectOneChoice label="Select Search" id="socSrch" autoSubmit="true" valueChangeListener="#pageFlowScope.wci.handleSelectSearch}"                                                        contentStyle="width:250px">
   <f:selectItems id="si1" value="#{pageFlowScope.wci.searchNames}"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>

public void handleSelectSearch(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {        
  if (valueChangeEvent.getNewValue() == null) {
                return;
  }     
  int selSearch = (Integer) valueChangeEvent.getNewValue(); 
  //...now write this to DB via code handle to view and field if desired           
}
```

At this point you can decide if you want to write out the index (the value) of the selected item to database via your backing bean code handle to the view, or you can get the label of the select item from your backing ArrayList of select items with some further coding, and populate that into the view, then commit. The view would have a field to receive what you wanted to put into it.